# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: android studio and andengine duplicate classes

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using Android Studio and AndEngine library and TexturePacker Extension using this link to setup:

[Setting Up AndEngine with Android Studio](http://javaprogrammernotes.blogspot.in/2014/05/settings-up-andengine-in-android-studio.html)

I'm getting that issue:

```
Error:Class org.andengine.BuildConfig has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.

1 error; aborting

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:

C:\Users\Diego\android-sdks\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Diego\NEXT\Next\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Diego\NEXT\Next\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt

Error Code:

1

Output:

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/andengine/BuildConfig;

at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.M...(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

1 error; aborting
```

I've tried everything. Cleaning project, deleting BuildConfig classes (they are created automatically in texturepacker library), excluding modules, reimporting third_party libraries... but nothing seems to fix it.

Here my build.gradle files:

App:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zmaxstudios.next"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
    compile project(':third_party:andengine')
    compile project(':third_party:texturepacker')
}
```

AndEngine > build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt')
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

Texturepacker > build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt')
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':third_party:andengine')
}
```

How can remove duplicated BuildConfig files? Or what should I do to fix that?
Thanks

Comment: what happens if you get rid of `compile project(':third_party:andengine')` from your app's build.gradle? It has also `Texturepacker` as dependency that is using also `andengine`

Comment: @Blackbelt exactly the same issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally solved the problem, that it wasn't with support libraries. I was getting the problem form third_party libraries, because manifest file of texturepacker library had the same package of andengine following the steps in link provided in the question, so BuildConfig.java classes was being duplicated. Now, the manifest files are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.andengine" >

    <application>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And texturepacker:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.andengine.extension.texturepacker.opengl.texture.util.texturepacker" >

<application>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Hope that can be helpfull.

Thanks all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like it lies in your dependencies, something like this, in my case.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'// and here's the issue
```

The Google Play Services libraries can be quite large and when combining in a lot of third party libraries or some newer Google libraries,  that can be redundancies as your experiencing.  I ran into a similar issues when implementing Google Cloud Storage. Typically I now just include what I really need from the android support libraries, i.e.

```
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev18-1.19.0'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-java6:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0'
```

Comment: But I'm not using the Google Play Services and is not requiered by code. Maybe i'm not understanding you.

Comment: Understood, that why I included 'in my case'.  so I'm not familar with all the libraries your using. Does it occur with a simplified version using just     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3' without your third party libraries, just for debugging the dex issue.

Answer (score 0):

can you please remove this line from dependencies I'm seeing here you are using two support libraries. clean and build your project

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
```